# Counterexample: a finite-order and non-unitary operator (Hilbert space).

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I need for this to be true but I can't find a suitable operator:

On a complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ let $T\in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$, which means a linear and continuous operator $T:\mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$; if $T$ has finite orded, i.e., that there exists an integer $k$ such that $T^k=\mathbb{I}$ (identity), T is not necessarily unitary.

Does somebody have at least a hint?

Comment: I would suggest writing down matrices in finite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbf{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$.